# Contador de Kilometros

Tags: android

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda, estou a criar um jogo que quanto mais o usuário andar a pé mais chances de poder receber recompensas mas eu não sei como fazer o contador de kilometros e ignora-se os kms percorridos a uma velocidade superior a 10km/h! Alguém me pode dar um norte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução simples seria capturar a localização do usuário a cada minuto e verificar a distância percorrida utilizando a classe Location do Android, como mostra o código abaixo.

```
Location localizacaoA = new Location("Ponto A");

localizacaoA.setLatitude(latA);
localizacaoA.setLongitude(lngA);

Location localizacaoB = new Location("Ponto B");

localizacaoB.setLatitude(latB);
localizacaoB.setLongitude(lngB);

float distancia = localizacaoA.distanceTo(localizacaoB); // Em metros
```

Caso a distancia nesse período foi menor que 180 metros (valor aproximado da distancia percorrida por uma pessoa à 10 km/h em 1 minuto), essa distancia é contabilizada.